# Can not access the Internet on a MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook

I can’t access the Internet using Safari on my MacBook Pro. The file may be corrupted. Is there any other way to connect to the Internet in order to load a different browser?

Comment: If you call Apple Support, I'm sure they will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FTP to download another browser. For example, get FireFox at `ftp.mozilla.org` under `/pub/Firefox/releases`